# Is there a way to automatically register custom dimension/metrircs via API on GA4?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics-4

I would like to register custom dimension/metric by sending a API request? Can this be done?

On Universal Analytics, there is a [insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/insert#java) command, is there an equivalent code for GA4?

Still looking for answers. I haven't found any command/code snippet to test on GA4.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics Admin API has ways to access and update the definitions. e.g:

[CreateCustomDimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rpc/google.analytics.admin.v1alpha#google.analytics.admin.v1alpha.AnalyticsAdminService.CreateCustomDimension)